# Compress folder in archive named as folder

Tags: applescript

I want to make a little script to compress folder. In fact I want to do exactly what is done when you right clic on a folder and select "compress": the zip file has the same name as the folder and when you clic on it, it creates back the folder and the files.
Here is my code:

```
set the_src to "Mac Info:Users:Maison:Desktop:Dest_So36"
set the_src to quoted form of POSIX path of the_src

set the_dest to "Mac Info:Users:Maison:Desktop:Dest_So36.zip"
set the_dest to quoted form of POSIX path of the_dest

do shell script "cd " & the_src & ";zip -r " & the_dest & " *"
```

If I use zip -r it takes all sub folder and file from the orginal folder but when unpacking, it give back the content of the original folder (subfolder and files) but not the main folder itself.
It I use zip -jr, it loose all the sub-folder (it get the files but not the folder).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing the directory is fine. You don't need the asterisk.

```
    do shell script "cd '/Users/Maison/Desktop/'; zip -r 'zip-a-dee-doo-dah.zip' 'Dest_So36' "
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using cd (changedirectory) to go INTO the folder?
When you are in the parent folder, you can use the zip -r command and it will work.

So I believe you command should become:

```
do shell script "zip -r " & the_dest & ".zip" & the_dest
```

Comment: Don't work unfortunatly. In fact if I use  do shell script the_src & ";zip -r " & the_dest & " *" the script seem to fall in an infinite loop like if it was packing the whole desktop. :/